# How to filter-out bracket in Makefile

Tags: makefile, filter, gnu-make

I have in issue where in some junk named files are getting generated in a directory; something like `(null).sv` and `(null)_connect_inputs.svh`

I have a makefile line to get a list files in that directory

```
TARGETS  = $(wildcard *.sv *.svh)
```

But i want to exclude those strangely named files. All these files would begin with `(null)`.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TARGETS := $(filter-out (null)%,$(wildcard *.sv *.svh))
```

- `$(filter-out)` can take a simple pattern with `%` as the wildcard
- Use `:=` to create an *immediate* variable—the `$(wildcard)`
  (or two in your case) 
  runs only once at definition time,
  rather than every time `${TARGETS}` is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this to work

```
TARGETS  = $(filter-out $(wildcard (null)*), $(wildcard *.sv *.svh))
```